# Retrieve the selection of a listbox or selectmode = extended in tkinter python

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I have a problem with retrieving the listbox selection when the selection mode is "extended". In fact my listbox items are scripts and I must be able to select multiple scripts and I can pass these scripts as  parameters to  my interpreter  whom role is to run these scripts one after the other and give me a result. the problem is that I can do everything only if select one script using this method:

```
def get_list(*event): 
 que2.put_nowait(script)
 seltext = liste.get(index)
 script=seltext 
 que2.put_nowait(script) 
def get_port(event) 
 index = liste1.curselection()[0] 
 seltext = liste1.get(index) 
 nb_port=seltext[1] 
 que1.put_nowait(nb_port) 
def call_interpreter1(): 
 b=que2.get(block=True) 
 a=que1.get(block=True) 
print "prameters are :" ,a ,b ,"\r\n"
c='python C:\\workspace\\Project_Interpreter\\ValidationTool-v1.0.py -s %s %s'%(b,a)
ps=sp.Popen(['cmd','/K',c],creationflags=0,shell=False,stdout=PIPE,stderr=sp.STDOUT,stdin=PIPE)
```

<sub>Translated with Google Translate</sub>

Comment: hello,
I am working with python tkinter, and i have problem when the selectmode is extended. In fact my list contains scripts and when I select one or more of these scripts it will pass my selection to the interpreter which will run these scripts one after the other and returns the result of the running.
So my problem is that I did all of this but with only one selection and I couldnt do it with extended selection with this method:
index = liste.curselection()[0]
seltext = liste.get(index)
script=seltext
que2.put_nowait(script)

Comment: you don't show enough of the code for us to help you. For example, how are you computing `index` in the above code snippet?

Comment: @BryanOakley I made some changes in my question and this is "grosso modo" how my code works.thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selection, call the `curselection` method on a listbox. This method returns a list containing the index of each selected item. You can then use the `get` method to get the item at that index.

```
for index in liste1.curselelction:
    item = liste1.get(index)
    print index, ":", item
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I did but I forgot to mention it in my code and I can put the selected scripts in a table.but my problem is passing the items one after another as arguments using que2.put_nowait(script).Apparently I have to use threads because I cant launch the scripts in the same time because they share the same port. problem is I am not able to know when the thread launching a script is done so I can launch the other .